# Matlab script moved to C but with different output for ode45

Tags: c, matlab, gsl, ode

I implemented an equivalent version of a Matlab script into C. In order to run ode45 I picked up GNU scientific library. But ode45 produces different outputs for each version. I've work for a while and I'm not able to find the problem.
I use gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply_fixed_step to make the same steps as in Matlab.

**Matlab script**

```
function ExpoGrowthEqn
% code to solve the exponential growth equation 
% dN/dt = r*N, N(0)=N0

% parameter values
r=0.2;
N0=10;

% numerical parameters
step=0.25;
tspan=[0:step:10];

% EXACT solution is: N(t)=N0 * exp(r*t)
for i=1:length(tspan)
    N(i,1)=N0*exp(r*tspan(1,i));
end
plot(tspan,N,'ob') %plots EXACT solution
hold on

% solve ODE using ode45
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-12,'AbsTol',1e-12);
    [t y] = ode45( @growth_eqn, tspan, N0, options, r);
    plot(t,y,'-r') %plot APPROXIMATE solution

    solutions=[t N y]
end

function dy = growth_eqn(t, y, r)
N=y(1)
dy=r*N;
end
```

**C code**

```
void fixed_step(void) {

    PARAM parameters;
    parameters.N = 11500000;
    parameters.beta = 0.1;
    parameters.gamma = 1/2;   

    double I0=500.0/parameters.N;
    double R0=9000000.0/parameters.N;
    double S0=1-I0-R0;
    double y[3] = {S0, I0, R0};

    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {func, NULL, 3, &parameters};
    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-12, 1e-12, 0);

    printf ("=== Initial values ===\n");
    printf ("y[0]=%6.15lf y[1]=%6.15lf y[2]=%6.15lf\n", y[0], y[1], y[2]);
    int length = 53;
    const double step = 0.25;
    double ti; double t = 0.0, tant = t;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= length*(1/step); i++)
    {
        printf ("%.2f(%3.d) -> t=%.2f %6.15lf %6.15lf %6.15lf\n", (float)tant, i, (float)t, y[0], y[1], y[2]);
        tant = t;
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply_fixed_step (d, &t, step/8, 8, y);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
        }
    }
    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);        
}
```

**Matlab output**

```
S                   I                   R
------------------------------------------------------------------
0.217347826086956   0.000043478260870   0.782608695652174
0.217347603416592   0.000038578485741   0.782613818097667
0.217347405784518   0.000034229664122   0.782618364551360
0.217347230418583   0.000030370797298   0.782622398784119
0.217347074884551   0.000026948321844   0.782625976793605
...
0.217345850226451   0.000000000007068   0.782654149766481
0.217345850226413   0.000000000006234   0.782654149767354
0.217345850226380   0.000000000005510   0.782654149768110
0.217345850226351   0.000000000004888   0.782654149768761
0.217345850226327   0.000000000004356   0.782654149769316
0.217345850226307   0.000000000003903   0.782654149769790
0.217345850226289   0.000000000003514   0.782654149770197
0.217345850226273   0.000000000003172   0.782654149770554
0.217345850226259   0.000000000002859   0.782654149770881
0.217345850226245   0.000000000002556   0.782654149771198
```

**C output**

```
=== Initial values ===
y[0]=0.217347826086956 y[1]=0.000043478260870 y[2]=0.782608695652174
0.00(   ) -> t=0.00 0.217347826086956 0.000043478260870 0.782608695652174
0.00(  1) -> t=0.25 0.217347589196436 0.000043715151390 0.782608695652174
0.25(  2) -> t=0.50 0.217347351015482 0.000043953332344 0.782608695652174
0.50(  3) -> t=0.75 0.217347111537070 0.000044192810757 0.782608695652174
0.75(  4) -> t=1.00 0.217346870754133 0.000044433593694 0.782608695652174
...
51.00(205) -> t=51.25 0.217258883883215 0.000132420464611 0.782608695652174
51.25(206) -> t=51.50 0.217258162689554 0.000133141658272 0.782608695652174
51.50(207) -> t=51.75 0.217257437570519 0.000133866777307 0.782608695652174
51.75(208) -> t=52.00 0.217256708504771 0.000134595843055 0.782608695652174
52.00(209) -> t=52.25 0.217255975470856 0.000135328876970 0.782608695652174
52.25(210) -> t=52.50 0.217255238447202 0.000136065900623 0.782608695652174
52.50(211) -> t=52.75 0.217254497412123 0.000136806935703 0.782608695652174
52.75(212) -> t=53.00 0.217253752343811 0.000137552004014 0.782608695652174
```

At the end of the second column there is a big different in data. In Matlab is almost 0  but not for C code.

**Matlab timestamps**

```
t =
                0
0.250000000000000
0.500000000000000
0.750000000000000
1.000000000000000
1.250000000000000
1.500000000000000
1.750000000000000
...
52.250000000000000
52.500000000000000
52.750000000000000
53.000000000000000
```

Comment: could you show at what timesteps your data for matlab is?! It seems to me that your matlab script runs until t=10 while your C code shows t=53?!

Comment: also: could it be a tolerance issue? The other answers (columns 1 and 3) are actually pretty much equally different (in absolute value) between matlab and C

Comment: It doesn't looks like this. Timestamps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab doesn't use fixed step sizes in its internal calculation when you specify `tspan` (read [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html)). It outputs at those chosen times. Hence you are doing two different calculations. Read [the first GSL example](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/ODE-Example-programs.html) how to use an adaptive time stepping with fixed output times.

Comment: I tried using gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply but results are almost the same as C, shown above. Despite Matlabs internal calculation, the second column shouldn't be that different.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I didn't include a small piece of code which was causing the problem. C code has been edited in order to add the missing 4 lines.
The problem is found:

> // gamma = 0.0
>   parameters.gamma = 1/2;

Which returns a 0 as a result. Obviously this is wrong. Declaring numbers with comma solves it.

> // gamma = 0.5
>   parameters.gamma = 1.0/2.0;